# Stripping some data from XML field using php

Tags: php, xml, wordpress, parsing

I've currently got an XML file that's being imported using a plugin on WordPress.

I've got a field that's currently importing the data and time automatically, but the field contains data in the current format

`<EndDate>2014-04-24T00:00:00+01:00</EndDate>`

I need to remove the time field somehow, but I'm stuck on how to do this (using php).

Is there a way of creating a function to remove the time, so that the field pulls in;

`<EndDate>YYYY-MM-DD</EndDate>`

Please help.

Comment: Can you include an example of what the XML file looks like?

Comment: `<EndDate>2014-04-24T00:00:00+01:00</EndDate>`

Answer (score 0):

You first need to exactly locate that field. You could use [simplexml](http://www.php.net/manual/ro/book.simplexml.php).
To output a formatted date you use the [date](http://www.php.net/manual/ro/function.date.php) function. It accepts a UNIX timestamp.
You obtain that timestamp by using the [strtotime](http://www.php.net/strtotime) function, that takes a date+time formatted as a string and returns a UNIX timestamp.

Comment: I know that a lot of people like SimpleXML, but in my opinion it is an awful way to manipulate an XML document.  Too much magic in the interface.  I would always chose DOMDocument for XML processing as it's behavior is explicit and well understood.

Comment: Currently i'm using WPAllImport to pull in the fields and it's working a treat.  But I want the field above I want to edit so that the time s removed.

All i've found is this http://www.wpallimport.com/documentation/advanced/execute-php/

But I'm lost now.  I know the field element will be called {EndDate[1]}.   If anybody has used this before, I'd be very grateful.

Comment: I agree with you but for simple step by step guides I prefer not to go into that kind of details.

Comment: Then please post your code so that we better understand what the problem is. Right now there does not seem to be one anymore.

Comment: Basically I need to use code like this;

Inside WP All Import:

`[your_function_name({EndDate[1]})]`

Inside your theme’s functions.php file:


`function your_function_name(){
 code to strip out time from xml field shown at the top of this page
 }`

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way you can do what you are looking at

```
$xml = "<reservation>
  <detail>
      <name>XXXXX</name>
            <EndDate>2014-04-24T00:00:00+01:00</EndDate>
  </detail>
  <detail>
      <name>YYYYY</name>
            <EndDate>2014-04-24T00:00:00+01:00</EndDate>
  </detail>
</reservation>";

$data = simplexml_load_string($xml);
//rint_r($data);
foreach ($data->detail as $obj)
{
    $end_date = $obj->EndDate ;
    $date = new DateTime($end_date);
  $obj->EndDate = $date->format("Y-m-d");
}

$new_xml = $data->asXML();

echo $new_xml ;
```

You can also save as file

```
 $data->asXML($file);
```

I have used for loading the string as

```
  $data = simplexml_load_string($xml);
```

You can load the file also as

```
  $data = simplexml_load_file($file);
```

Answer (score 0):

Xpath can be used so fetch nodes from the XML DOM, but it can extract scalar values, too. It has even some functions. One of them is `string-before()` that returns the part of a string before an substring.

```
$xml = "<EndDate>2014-04-24T00:00:00+01:00</EndDate>";

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXml($xml);    
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);

var_dump(
  $xpath->evaluate('substring-before(//EndDate, "T")')
);
```

Output: https://eval.in/141939

```
string(10) "2014-04-24"
```

Comment: So would I just put this within a new function on WordPress?